# Disable logback log file deletion by setting maxHistory to zero

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am trying to disable the log file deletion in `logback`.

I searched the documentation but found no way to accomplish this.

However, the source code seems to depend on `maxHistory` flag set to 0 which means unbounded history. [see](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/3ce9f04d6e5f40155839cfe9ada90d94543050c0/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/CoreConstants.java#L202) and [see](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/3ce9f04d6e5f40155839cfe9ada90d94543050c0/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.java#L107).

but hence I cannot find it documented anywhere, I am afraid to use so to be changed in the future without any declarations!

So my question, is it documented somewhere I don't know about?

Comment: I don't find the default value in the official documentation too. But everything indicates that you're correct, the value 0 disables the deletion (which wouldn't be recommended). In this Issue the SpringBoot team also confirm the semantics of the value 0 in MaxHistory. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15875

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. This is now fixed as can be seen in the [relevant documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpMaxHistory)